# mysql query to exclude sunday from two dates

Tags: mysql

If complaint filed on 5 pm on Saturday and closed on 1 pm on Monday, ticket should exclude sunday 24 hours.

Complaint Creation Date:24 Sept 2014, 6:00 PM Sat

Complaint Closed Date  : 26 Sept 2014 ,6:00 PM Monday

Time taken :1 day not 2 day

Need Suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DAYNAME(DATE_ADD(Complaint_Creation_Date, INTERVAL 1 day)) = 'Sunday'
       THEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,Complaint_Creation_Date,Complaint_Closed_Date))/24 - 1 AS "TIME TAKEN"
       ELSE
       (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,Complaint_Creation_Date,Complaint_Closed_Date))/24 AS "TIME TAKEN"
       END
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```